# C++: Using BFS to find a path through a matrix

Tags: c++, graph, segmentation-fault

Suppose one is given a matrix

> ***1*** **1** 0 0 0
>
> 0 **1 1** 0 0
>
> 1 0 **1** 1 0
>
> 0 1 **1** 0 0
>
> 0 0 **1 1** ***1***

and asked to find a path *only passing through ones* from the top-left point (bold italic 1) to the bottom-right point (another similar 1). Once such path is shown in bold.

I have been trying to implement this in C++, but I'm - surprise - segfaulting. More importantly, I can't work out any way to do this without duplicating a lot of code.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> Coords;

struct Point {
    int x, y;
    int val;
    bool visited;
    Point (int a, int b, int v) : x(a), y(b), val(v), visited(false) {}
};

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<vector<Point> > pts(n, vector<Point>(n, Point(0, 0, 0)));
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            cin >> temp;
            pts[i][j] = Point(i, j, temp);
        }
    }

    queue<Coords> toVisit;

    toVisit.push(Coords(0,0));
    Coords cur(0, 0);
    vector<Coords> neighbors;

    while(!toVisit.empty()) {
        cur = toVisit.back();
        toVisit.pop();
        int x = cur.first, y = cur.second;
        pts[x][y].visited = true;

        bool xgt0 = x > 0, xltm = x < n;
        bool ygt0 = y > 0, yltm = y < n;

        //  x-1,y-1 x  ,y-1 x+1,y-1
        //  x-1,y   x  ,y   x+1,y
        //  x-1,y+1 x  ,y+1 x+1,y+1

        if(xgt0) {
                    if(!pts[x-1][y].visited)   toVisit.push(Coords(x-1,y));
            if(ygt0 && !pts[x-1][y-1].visited) toVisit.push(Coords(x-1,y-1));
            if(yltm && !pts[x-1][y+1].visited) toVisit.push(Coords(x-1,y+1));
        }

        if(ygt0 && !pts[x][y-1].visited) toVisit.push(Coords(x,y-1));
        if(yltm && !pts[x][y+1].visited) toVisit.push(Coords(x,y+1));

        if(xltm) {
                    if(!pts[x+1][y].visited)   toVisit.push(Coords(x+1,y));
            if(ygt0 && !pts[x+1][y-1].visited) toVisit.push(Coords(x+1,y-1));
            if(yltm && !pts[x+1][y+1].visited) toVisit.push(Coords(x+1,y+1));
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            cout << pts[i][j].visited << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work at all. How would I go about fixing this?

And how an I write this program without duplicating so much code in the BFS neighbour-addition segment?

---

### Edit

Solved, here is the code (which now completely solves the original problem).

A little bit of refactoring was done to decrease code duplication, but more could be done, for example turning the `if(something && proceed(...)) push(...)` into `if(something) pushIfOK(...)`. This is left as an exercise to the adventurous reader with a little more time on his hands than I do at the moment. :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> Coords;

struct Point {
    int x, y;
    bool val; //passable or not?
    bool visited;
    Point (int a, int b, bool v) : x(a), y(b), val(v), visited(false) {}
};

bool proceed(Point);

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<vector<Point> > pts(n, vector<Point>(n, Point(0, 0, true)));
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            cin >> temp;
            pts[i][j] = Point(i, j, temp == 1);
        }
    }

    queue<Coords> toVisit;

    toVisit.push(Coords(0,0));
    Coords cur(0, 0);
    vector<Coords> neighbors;

    while(!toVisit.empty()) {
        cur = toVisit.back();
        toVisit.pop();
        int x = cur.first, y = cur.second;
        pts[x][y].visited = true;

        bool xgt0 = x > 0, xltm = x < n - 1;
        bool ygt0 = y > 0, yltm = y < n - 1;

        //  x-1,y-1 x  ,y-1 x+1,y-1
        //  x-1,y   x  ,y   x+1,y
        //  x-1,y+1 x  ,y+1 x+1,y+1

        if(ygt0 && proceed(pts[x][y-1])) toVisit.push(Coords(x,y-1));
        if(yltm && proceed(pts[x][y+1])) toVisit.push(Coords(x,y+1));

        if(xgt0) {
            if(proceed(pts[x-1][y])) toVisit.push(Coords(x-1,y));
            if(ygt0 && proceed(pts[x-1][y-1])) toVisit.push(Coords(x-1,y-1));
            if(yltm && proceed(pts[x-1][y+1])) toVisit.push(Coords(x-1,y+1));
        }

        if(xltm) {
            if(proceed(pts[x+1][y])) toVisit.push(Coords(x+1,y));
            if(ygt0 && proceed(pts[x+1][y-1])) toVisit.push(Coords(x+1,y-1));
            if(yltm && proceed(pts[x+1][y+1])) toVisit.push(Coords(x+1,y+1));
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            cout << pts[i][j].visited << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

bool proceed(Point p) { return p.val && !p.visited; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have been trying to implement this in C++, but I'm - surprise - segfaulting.

Your problem with the segfaults is due to the high value check:

```
if (yltm && !pts[x][y+1].visited) toVisit.push(Coords(x,y+1));
```

Note that when `y = n - 1` `yltm == true` and you attempt to access `pts[x][n]` entry in your array, which doesn't exist (its at position n + 1, zero based indexing and all).

Unfortunately, due to the nature of your input data, you need to check for boundaries and have all the duplicated-looking code, but I don't think you can avoid it in this case. A hint for after you fix the segfaulting and move on to trying to find the actual path between the corners: Try keeping track of the "depth" of your search and use that to find the path back to the top left from the bottom right.

Comment: Thank you. This is actually a flood-fill program, so I don't need the path. :)